I am trying to generate a dashboard in humanforce that can highlight clients of a particular employment type that have worked across regions
I am trying to create a dashboard listing all casual staff appearing in timesheet rosters for more than one region for the defined time period.
It isn't quite as intuitive as working with power BI, there is query functionality to perform more complex data transformations but not sure what language it's in and how to leverage it's systems to do relational filtering required to nail this data down.
Hoping someone with experience with this platform may have advice, guidance or even a working solution.
I have been able to create a pivot table that can be manually scoured to identify rosters counted in regions using conditional formatting but this is not the ideal solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
